# Linux mint - black screen

Tags: boot, linux-mint, hdmi

Can anyone help?

Running intense pc pro (http://www.fit-pc.com/IntensePC/docs/Intense-PC-specifications.pdf).

USB keyboard and mouse, HDMI (1080p certified) cable connected to Samsung series 6 HDTV with 1920x1080 resolution

PC came with Linux pre-installed but booting into OS was unsuccessful due to black screen.
No Grub option was available.

Downloaded Mint 13 cinnamon 64 bit and installed(no problems). However, when restarted, pc had a black screen.

Also tried Mint 14 but same results.

The Kicker is Puppy Linux 5.3.1. boots fine for 1920x1080x24.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going to the Terminal and reinstalling cinnamon, as that is how I fixed it. Type these commands, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
sudo reboot
```